# How can I read File from MediaStore in Relative Path?

Tags: android, uri, mediastore

In Android 10 or higher, I used MediaStore to save files in Downloads, shared storage.
The code I used to save the file is as follows:

```
        GlobalScope.launch {
        val values = ContentValues().apply {
            put(MediaStore.Downloads.DISPLAY_NAME, "file.txt")
            put(MediaStore.Downloads.MIME_TYPE, "text/plain")
            put(MediaStore.Downloads.IS_PENDING, 1)
            put(MediaStore.Downloads.RELATIVE_PATH,Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS+ File.separator+"MyApp/SubDir")
        }

        val collection = MediaStore.Downloads.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL_PRIMARY)
        val item = contentResolver.insert(collection, values)!!

        contentResolver.openFileDescriptor(item, "w", null).use {
            FileOutputStream(it!!.fileDescriptor).use { outputStream ->
                outputStream.write("test file".toByteArray())
                outputStream.close()
            }
        }

        values.clear()
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.IS_PENDING, 0)
        contentResolver.update(item, values, null, null)
```

Now my file is save in Downloads/myApp/subDir/file.txt

If so, how can I read this file if I don't know the Uri of this file but know the RELATIVE_PATH used to save it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is now possible with the helps of [SimpleStorage](https://github.com/anggrayudi/SimpleStorage):

```kotlin
val fileList = MediaStoreCompat.fromRelativePath(this, Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)

val singleFile = MediaStoreCompat.fromRelativePath(this, Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS + "/MyApp/SubDir/", "file.txt")
```

Comment: Adding to the Answer, For Java we can't access fromRelativePath() method like this as Java considered it as we are calling it from the static context so what we can do is `MediaStoreCompat.INSTANCE.fromRelativePath(getContext(), Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS + "/MyApp/SubDir/", "file.txt");`

Comment: I appreciate creating the library, but this is an incomplete answer to the question: this shows how to get some sort of a "handle "(type DocumentFile), but not how to actually read it, as getting an InputStream or copying it somewhere else. Extending the SimpleStorage README with an example like this would also be appreciated

Comment: If you are going to promote your library for your answer, please disclose it in the answer. Something like "This uses my library on GitHub" would be fine I think.